# DataGridViewComboBoxCell not working in VSTO

Tags: c#, datagridview, vsto

Done this simple datagrid in a custom Region Form:
[image: Configuration]

Simple with fixed items (a,b,c,d), still when launching, nothing combobox is greyed out and I can't select anything (and yes, "Readonly" is set to false").

[image: Result]

What did I wrong?
Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Juste needed to make the whole datagridview editable and now it works.